# Side-by-side images

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

I am trying to put two images side by side using the minipages option. But my captions are rather long - I want to have more space between the two images for obvious reasons. How do I do this?

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{exp2a}
  \captionof{figure}{The circuit setup to calculate the current through      the resistor using Ohm's Law with $V_{in}=1.00\pm5\%  V$ and $R=10.0\pm5\%  M\Omega$.}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{exp2b}
  \captionof{figure}{The circuit setup to measure the current through the resistor using Ohm's Law $V_{in}=1.00\pm5\%  V$ and $R=10.0\pm5\%   M\Omega$.}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output when compiled:
[image: I obviously want to seperate the captions so there is a space between them, but I can't figure out how!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]% <-- don't use option H!
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}% <-- reduced minipage width (that gives space between them
  \centering% <--
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{exp2a}% <-- width of images is equal to mini page's width
  \captionof{figure}{The circuit setup to calculate the current through the resistor using Ohm's Law with $V_{in}=1.00\pm5\%  V$ and $R=10.0\pm5\%  M\Omega$.}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}
\hfil % <-- changed from \hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}% <-- reduced minipage width
  \centering% <-- is sensible only if picture is smaller than minipage width
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{exp2b}
  \captionof{figure}{The circuit setup to measure the current through the resistor using Ohm's Law $V_{in}=1.00\pm5\%  V$ and $R=10.0\pm5\%   M\Omega$.}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Above code should be self-explanatory (see comments in it). Result is:

[image]

**Off topic:**
In preamble of code you have duplicates of packages: `xcolor` is extension version of `color`, i.e. `color` is surplus; `caption` is loaded three times. For showing your problem, most of packages in your preamble is surplus. I use `demo` option of `graphicx` package because I haven't your image. In final document you had to delete this option. Also, use of `H` option for picture placement is not good idea. It can cause very ugly document form.

Comment: Thank you - I am very new to Latex so I wasn't sure what packages to include. I mainly used a template to start my first document and then just copied the packages each time. Why shouldn't I use [H] for picture placement? I haven't had any issues with it or the float package.

Comment: Let me simplify: placement `H` destroy main advantages of LaTeX  -- float of figures and tables to place where they have enough space for their placement in place where they are in the text or on the top of the next page -- and transform LaTeX something like Word. Float of them is enabled with `htb`.